# Select higher value

Tags: sql, teradata, proc-sql

I have this dataset:

```
Var1  t  avg
AA   1  0.02
AA   0  0.21
BB   1  0.05
BB   0  0.20
CC   1  0.10
CC   0  0.14
```

Built as follows

```
Proc sql;
    Select 
    Var1,
    t,
    Avg(var2) as avg
    From my_data
    Group by 1,2
    Order by 1,2; quit;
```

My expected output would be

```
    AA   0  0.21
    BB   0  0.20
    CC   0  0.14
```

Could you please give me some tips on how to do it?
I have been using max function to do it. I would try to split the problem in two steps: the first select for each group (AA,BB, and CC) the higher value, then I would select the maximum between these values. I do not know if it is the right approach

Comment: . . It is unclear what you want as the result set.  One row?  One row per `id`?  One row per `t`?  What do you mean by "variable"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: *be stored as var3 and the logic which allowed me to get this result (e.g. a case when which select this value among the others should be saved as var 3).* I don't get it. If Gordon's answer doesn't help, you should try to describe your logic clearly.

Comment: I would need just to store the value as var3. Sometimes it happens that, when you filter your variables, you use a case when or max or other function or condition which define a new variable. This would be the case. I have tried to use top and qualify but since it is within a proc sql, I get some errors (please see the code above)

Comment: Which value? You get three columns, `AA   0  0.21`, what should this `var3` contain?

Comment: What I should select is per each group the var1 having higher avg. The logic behind this selection should allow me to define this new variable. But what I am interested in should be each value with higher avg. I am sorry, but I cannot explain better than this :( To avoid any confusion I deleted all mentions on var3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one row with the highest average, use `top`:

```
Select top 1 Var1, t, Avg(var2) as avg
From my_data
Group by 1,2
Order by avg desc;
```

If you want this *per `t`*, then use `qualify` and `row_number()`:

```
select Var1, t, Avg(var2) as avg
from my_data
group by 1,2
qualify row_number() over (partition by var1 order by avg desc) = 1;
```

Comment: @Math . . . That is the second query in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Does it work also within a proc sql?

Comment: @Math . . . Your question is tagged Teradata, not `proc sql`.  It is valid Teradata code, so it should work in pass-through mode.

Comment: Apologies Gordon. I did not know there was another tag for proc sql. I fixed it. Sorry but I am new with SQL and proc SQL

Comment: @Math . . . In native proc SQL, this would be a bit more complicated (and less efficient).  I assume this is working in pass-through mode.

Comment: I think I should do something like ranking the observations having higher value, then assigning a rank = 1 (if in descending order) and select only cases where rank = 1. But I do not know how to write it

Comment: @Math . . . Ask another question with the proc-sql tag.

Comment: did it. Thanks Gordon Linoff